# Python error:“IndexError: string index out of range”

Tags: python, file, text

I import my txt file as str by using with open

```
with open('./doc', 'r') as f:
dat = f.readlines()
```

then I want to clean the data by using a for loop

```
docs = []
for i in dat:
if i.strip()[0] != '<':
    docs.append(i)
```

error returns

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-131-92a67082e677> in <module>()
      1 docs = []
      2 for i in dat:
----> 3     if i.strip()[0] != '<':
      4         docs.append(i)

IndexError: string index out of range
```

but if I change the code like this,just select the first 3000 lines, the code works.

```
docs = []
for i in dat[:3000]:
if i.strip()[0] != '<':
    docs.append(i)
```

My txt file contains 93408 lines ,why I can't select them all?
        thx!

Comment: Indention if i.strip()[0] != '<':

Comment: because one of your lines is empty

Comment: Empty lines possibly? Try `if i.strip() and i.strip()[0] != '<':`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one or more lines could be empty, you need to check it before take first elem

```
if i.strip() != "" and i.strip()[0] != '<':
    docs.append(i)
```

Comment: Small correction: `if i.strip() != ''` because `i` is a string. Furthermore, you can shorten that to `if i.strip()` because of truthiness testing. See my comment in the question too.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ my old pal! Long time no see, always so kind, always so nice! Always right.. Thanks so much!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ the code works! thank you for your help, as a beginner your kindness shining my way

Comment: @HerryWang don't forget to accept the answer with the check box! ;)

Comment: @HerryWang Well asked questions will be rewarded with help. :-)